# LibGDX: Why is Gdx.files.internal() working and Gdx.files.local() not?

Tags: libgdx, file-handling

HI I am trying to run a LibGDX application on Android and I try to load a JSON File where I need read/write access.

That file is in the assets folder.

When I try to load it with Gdx.files.local("file.json"), it says that it cannot be found (it works with Gdx.files.internal(), however then it is read-only).

Actually, that worked well in another project, and, somehow, now it does not.

I searched for an answer and I cannot find anything, do you have an idea how to solve that problem?

Comment: Local and internal are different directories. Load it from internal only if it doesn't exist in local. Save it in local.

Comment: Alright, now it works, I am just confused because I did not have to do that in another project. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation of Libgdx `FileHandle` types](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling#file-storage-types), the `Local` and `Internal` `FileHandle`s use a different path under the hood:
- The `Internal` `FileHandle` is relative to the assets directory on Android and has a fall back to the `ClassPath` `FileHandle`. It is always read-only!
- The `Local` `FileHandle` is relative to the internal (private) App-Storage on Android. You can use this `FileHandle` to read and write.

So basicly it is not possible to write to a file in the internal stoarage, use the local storage instead.
As you want to "ship" this file with your application, you might want to copy it from internal to local storage when the app is started for the first time, so that the application has read and write access to it.